# How can I calculate bug fixing time for a bug report in JIRA Issue Tracking System?

Tags: jira

In JIRA has three fields (https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/TRANS-1861?jql=)
1. Created
2. Updated
3. Resolved
We can calculate bug fixing time in two ways
1. Bug fixing time= Resolved -Created
2. Bug fixing time=Updated-Created
After fixing the bug, fixing code is tested by tester. If the tester pass the fixing then the bug is closed. Otherwise, developers modify the code and try to fix again. In that case, there is a gap between resolved and closed date. The problem of updated field is the field updated every time someone work on the bug report.
So, I need to know how long time takes a developer to fix a particular bug. If I calculate by this equation (Bug fixing time= Resolved -Created) is it OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to calculate the bug fixing time, it depends on what are you trying to do and your process. Here are some consideration:

1. When the bug is reported, when/how do you triage it? Not every bug
   reported is a real bug, there are cases where it is work as
   designed, training issue or simply enhancement request.
2. When the bug is assigned, when does the developer start working on
   it. Does your developer change the status from New to Working when
   they start working on it?
3. Once the bug fixes is done, how does it being tested? If the test
   pass, will the status be changed to Ready?
4. Once the bug fixes is deployed and validated on production, does the
   issue status change to Closed?

To look at the detail of the status changes, you can use the `expand=changelog` parameter via the REST API and iterate thru the changes to calculate the time in each state. Here is an example:

https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/issue/TRANS-1861?expand=changelog

Comment: Thanks for your answer.